# How to use LightInject with Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms, unity-container, light-inject

I have a legacy ASP.Net Web Forms application targeting .Net 4.8 in which I would like to use dependency injection. Our engine of choice is LightInject.

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641383/1010492) and the source code of [ContainerServiceProvider.Cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebFormsDependencyInjection/blob/master/src/UnityAdapter/ContainerServiceProvider.cs) from the Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity project, I was able to create my own [IServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IServiceProvider);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.8) container for LightInject and assign it to the [HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpruntime.webobjectactivator?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Web.HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.8);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8):

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    // Register the service provider
    ContainerServiceProvider containerServiceProvider = new ContainerServiceProvider(HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator);
    HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator = containerServiceProvider;

    // Register services used with dependency injection
    var container = containerServiceProvider.Container;
    container.Register<IDummyService, DummyService>();
}
```

I am able to register my services, and access them via `HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator.GetService()`.

However, I am yet to see constructor (or property) injection in action... When I declare an ASPX page (say About.aspx) with the following constructor, I get an error when I access the page: "'About' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

```
public About(IDummyService dummy)
{
    ...
}
```

[image: A screenshot of the error that occurs when accessing the page]

**EDIT**: this was because the website was targetting an older version of .Net in its config file. [Retargetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170567/what-do-the-targetframework-settings-mean-in-web-config-in-asp-net-mvc) 4.8 fixed this first issue.

Now the issue is different: if I debug the `ContainerServiceProvider` I implemented, I can see that .Net tries to get the `ASP.about_aspx` service that's defined in a temporary assembly (eg: `C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/e15e9fc8/41270200/App_Web_cdps00j5.DLL`), which my LightInject container doesn't know.

So I'm not sure what else I have to do to have constructor injection working in my pages. I'm assuming that I have to tell LightInject that my pages are candidates for dependency injection somehow, but I have no idea on how to do that (the documentation is very scarce). Also, I'm wondering how Unity works because I couldn't see any magic in the source code of [Microsoft.AspNet.WebFormsDependencyInjection.Unity](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebFormsDependencyInjection) apart from the implementation of the `ContainerServiceProvider.cs` that I reused.

**UPDATE:** I have tried manually registering all the types that implement pages, but it did not work:

```
foreach (var assembly in BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>())
{
    try
    {
        container.RegisterAssembly(
            assembly,
            () => new LightInject.PerScopeLifetime(),
            (serviceType, implementingType) => serviceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Web.UI.Page)));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this comes a bit late as I just saw this question.  I believe it's because it's a WebForms Website (compiled at runtime) as opposed to a Web Application (pre compiled).  I'm attempting to use [Jehoel.AspNetDependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jehoel.AspNetDependencyInjection/4.0.0) in looking to modernize and eventually migrate away from WebForms and I've run into the same issue - it doesn't seem to call the activator.  However, I'm still investigating this.

Comment: Well it looks like there is no way to do it with a WebForms WebSite it has to be converted to a WebForms WebApplication.  You can see @Dai's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238742/constructor-injection-not-working-in-net-4-7-2-dependency-injection-in-asp-net)